# "Submitted form is invalid" when adding a product to cart : Sylius Cart Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I apologize if this seems to be a very naive question..but i've just learnt Symfony2 and trying to learn the workings of [Sylius](http://sylius.com/get-started).

When I add a product to the cart it seems to always  return the error :

> Submitted form is invalid

I have searched the solution to this but nothing seems to be documented (or have I
missed it ??)

I also commented the validation section but still get the same error. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just post your code here . I think it might be the structure of your form .

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the code whatsoever but it gives an error while resolving the item `try {
            $item = $this->getResolver()->resolve($emptyItem, $request);
        } catch (ItemResolvingException $exception) {
            // Write flash message
            $this->dispatchEvent(SyliusCartEvents::ITEM_ADD_ERROR, new FlashEvent($exception->getMessage()));

            return $this->redirectToCartSummary();
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has something to do with having options on products. I had the same error and looking through the profiler at the Doctrine info there was an error for 2 of the objects that were being persisted to the database. Specifically, it couldn't map Sylius\Bundle\AssortmentBundle\Entity\CustomizableProduct or Sylius\Bundle\AssortmentBundle\Entity\Variant\Variant.

To fix it I had to  Generate Variants of the product which is on the product details page in the admin area. Without having variants to add to the cart, it couldn't choose a specific type of the product to add to the cart.

I feel like this should produce a better error, especially when running the app in dev mode.

Comment: Thanks...it was the same thing :)